Status Code: ACTION_NOT_AUTHORIZED - Permission not enabled to execute action
I'm testing our Magento site using sandbox keys but got error "Status Code: ACTION_NOT_AUTHORIZED - Permission not enabled to execute action". Our test keys have default permissions. I checked the log but nothing helpful.
Thank you
Review the settings in Magento admin and in GP. Using another sandbox account and got it work.
